# Error when trying to print an InfoPath form to PDF

Tags: infopath, form, printing

Trying to print out an InfoPath form as a PDF generates this message alongside a Text document rather than a .PDF document.

> %%[ ProductName: Distiller ]%%
>   06bmfqu not found, using Courier.
>   %%[ Error: invalidfont; OffendingCommand: xshow ]%%
>
> Stack:
>   [217 199 157 199 191 140 169 210 91 195 134 210 92 169 156 91 191 211
>   210 90 101 210 134 199 188 140 92 134 181 0]
>   (
>   
>   
>   
>   )
>
> %%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
>   %%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%

All works fine when printing a hard copy to a printer.

Any tip to prevent this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following when you are filling out a form in Office InfoPath 2007:

On the File menu, point to Export To, and then click PDF or XPS.
In the File Name list, type or select a name for the form.
In the Save as type list, click PDF.
If you want to open the file immediately after saving it, select the Open file after publishing check box. This check box is available only if you have a PDF reader installed on your computer.
Next to Optimize for, do one of the following, depending on whether file size or print quality is more important to you:
If the form requires high print quality, click Standard (publishing online and printing).
If the print quality is less important than file size, click Minimum size (publishing online).
Click Publish.

Greetings,
Peter